# How to implement Bizrate survey tag on 5% views of the Order Confirmation page in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am looking to implement Bizrate on the order confirmation page but it should be implemented to only 5% of order confirmation page views. need help how to do that how we can fire a tag based on the some percentage of traffic or page views.

I am looking to implement Bizrate on the order confirmation page but it should be implemented to only 5% of order confirmation page views. need help how to do that how we can fire a tag based on the some percentage of traffic or page views.

Answer (score 0):

If this is based on page views (and does not take sessions or users into account) then this is pretty straightforward. 5% is one in twenty, so generate a random number between 1 and 20, and then create a trigger that only fires for a specific number. If you have enough page impressions to achieve a random distribution, each number will come up for 5% of page views.